# Display Progressbar animation in splash window - wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, progress-bar, splash-screen, blend

I have used a progressbar in my Splash Window and set the property IsIndeterminate="True" to have continuous animation. However when I run the project, the splash screen is displayed initially but the progressbar animation is not seen.

Below is the code I have written in the main window

```
public partial class revised_mainwindow : Window
{
    public revised_mainwindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


        var ssc = new SplashWindow();
        ssc.Show();
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        ssc.Close();



    }
```

Comment: Thread.Sleep is very bad thing to use here, as it is blocking the main thread and so your animation is not running. Instead you can create an async method and use await Task.Delay(5000); in that (which will not block your ui thread). Either way, using delay or sleep is not the best way to go and instead you should be awaiting your loading screen code . Show us more code and we might be able to help you with what you are doing.

Comment: And have a read here to see the problems with Thread.Sleep http://blogs.msmvps.com/peterritchie/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program/